# Mapping DTO inside DTO using ModelMapper

Tags: java, spring, dto, modelmapper

I have the next entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Student extends BaseEntity {

    private String identifier;

    @NotNull
    @Embedded
    private UserInformation userInformation;
```

```
@Embeddable
@ToString
public class UserInformation {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
}
```

And I create a DTO for the Student class:

```
@Data
@ToString
public class CreateStudentDTO {

    @NotNull
    private UserInformationDTO userInformation;
}
```

```
@Data
@ToString
public class UserInformationDTO {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    private String lastName;
}
```

But because UserInformationDTO and UserInformation I did not find a solution to map them.
This is what I tried in the Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public CreateStudentDTO createStudent(@RequestBody CreateStudentDTO studentDTO) {
        System.out.println("dto: " + studentDTO);
        TypeMap<CreateStudentDTO, Student> propertyMapper = modelMapper
                .createTypeMap(CreateStudentDTO.class, Student.class);
        propertyMapper.addMapping(CreateStudentDTO::getUserInformation, Student::setUserInformation);
        Student student = modelMapper.map(studentDTO, Student.class);
        System.out.println(student);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the field in Student after mapping will be: `userInformation=UserInformation(firstName=null, lastName=null, dateOfBirth=null, address=null, gender=null)`
I want to map only the firstName and lastName for first, then I can map others if this works.